# Audio input not working using Cordova WebRTC plugin on Android

Tags: android, audio-streaming, webrtc

I'm trying to use the  
[cordova opentok plugin](https://github.com/songz/cordova-plugin-opentok) to create a WebRTC app on my android device. I'm able to send both audio and video from my device using the plugin, but I am only able to receive video. I am getting some errors/warnings that seem to be related the audio problems, but I'm not sure how to debug these:

```
05-12 14:15:53.142: W/AudioRecord(14619): AUDIO_INPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
```

When I try to run the application on Google Glass, both audio input and output are not working, and I get the following warnings:

```
05-12 12:58:29.950: W/AudioTrack(26682): AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
05-12 12:58:31.192: W/AudioRecord(26682): AUDIO_INPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
```

I'm also getting the following error while streaming:

```
05-12 13:26:23.702: D/audio_hw_primary(183): select_devices: out_snd_device(0: )  in_snd_device(16: handset-mic)
05-12 13:26:23.702: D/(183): Failed to fetch the lookup information of the device 00000004 
05-12 13:26:23.702: E/ACDB-LOADER(183): Error: ACDB AudProc vol returned = -19
```

I've searched these errors and haven't come up with anything useful for debugging this problem. Any suggestions on how to debug these, or where to go from here? Thanks.

Comment: My application is the same as yours. I also creating WebRTC application using cordova. In my case I getting this strings too but in my app audio stream works fine. You can post your code and I will see.